# C# POST runs method multiple times even but should only run once

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple view. The user fills out a form on the previous page and then submits the Ajax form. The form validates that everything, including payment, is good. If it is not, it stays on the same page with an error (hence the AJAX), but if it is good, then it redirects to the confirmation page via:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("PYGConfirmationPost", "PYG")';
```

Which loads a view that looks like the image below. The drop-down consists of any emails that were added on the previous screen. So it's very simple. There are only 3 things of jQuery/JavaScript on the page. One is google analytics. the other two are below the image.

[image: Confirmation Page]

```
//Prevents user from going back to the form. Used and works on many Views.
history.pushState("", "", "../Home/Index")

//auto submit in 30 seconds
$(document).ready(function () {

    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#PreSubmit").trigger('click');
    }, 30000);
});

//After 30 seconds, submit GA and then submit the form.
$('#PreSubmit').click(function () {
    //Submit google analytics here
    $("#submit").trigger('click');
});
```

Here is the method it calls. I put a break point at the top and the 'return RedirectToAction'. For some reason, once it gets to the bracket ( } ) right below the return Redirect... it will jump back up to the top and start the method over.
**EDIT:** I deleted everything except the return RedirectToAction and it is still doing the loop.

```
    [RequireAuth]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PYGConfirmationPost(PYG SignUp)
    {
      //EDIT: The code in the controller isn't the issue. I deleted everything except for the return statement and it still does the strange loop.

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

It consistently will run the method 2x, but if I step through it, it will do it anywhere from 2-6x. I usually give up after 6x, so it may do more. One time, it only did the method once.

I have tried moving the RedirectToAction under OperationKillTheCookies() and it didn't fix it. I tried changing RedirectToAction to View and it didn't fix it.

I was thinking maybe the time limit from jQuery was affecting it, but no matter how fast or how slow I allow the loop to go, it behaves the same.

**Edit** I created a test using selenium web driver (specifically, chrome driver). It does not loop the method when the test method is ran.

**Edit 2** It does not do this from every computer. 2 other people have tried it and it worked as desired a couple times each. However, 2 other people have tried it and it fired off too many times. I have no idea what the issue could be.

Comment: Try to use google console (F12) and check the network, is that posted 2-6 times from client side too? if yes, it will narrow down the scope.

Comment: Hello. No it doesn't look like the browser/client-side is the culprit. It's only submitting the form once. And it does exactly what it should do the first time; it jumps to the correct method and runs through it. But then it runs it again.

Comment: It totally sounds client side but it's strange that you're only seeing one request.  None of this may help, but: have you tried moving the event handler creation to inside the $(document).ready?  I'd also try $('#PreSubmit').off().click just to be sure you're not getting multiple handlers attached to the button click.  I'm also not that familiar with .trigger('click'); I usually write it just .click();, and in fact, I would probably write that whole line as setTimeout('$("#PreSubmit").click();', 30000);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Jrud for giving me the inspiration to find a 'solution'. I have no idea what's wrong with it, but I found the fix. I changed the trigger(click) to just click(). didnt fix it. Put it in $(document).ready(). Same result.

However, If I put the Google Analytics stuff in a function outside of the click, then it works. The GA code doesn't do anything but submit to google analytics, as per the GA documentation. So no one knows what the exact cause was.

The strange part is is that it doesn't look like it's firing twice from the client-side. It looks like it loops the method in the controller, which shouldn't have anything to do with jQuery or GA. So, basically, witches were causing the issue.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    eCommerce();


    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#PreSubmit").click();
    }, 30000);

    //send eCommerce and then submit the form because I have zero idea how to use Google Analytics and this feels right.
    $('#PreSubmit').click(function () {
        $("#submit").click();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe add

```
    return false;
```

to $('#PreSubmit').click()  :

```
     $('#PreSubmit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
            $("#submit").click();
    return false;
        });
```

and why not separate call to GA as its own function?

```
    function callga()
   {
    ga(......);
    }
```